# ListActivity - list not showing

Tags: java, android

When I try to set the listAdapter or the adapter(`#setListAdapter(), #getListView().setAdapter()`) it does not show. When I tried to set a ListView individually it works just fine. It doesn't work either when I run it in `#runOnUiThread()`. Why is my list not showing?

The following is my code

```
public class ShopActivity extends ListActivity {

    private Intent mainIntent = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.shop);
        mainIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        String[] items = {"Test"};
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

        //ListView view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

         //view.setAdapter(adapter);
        getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onBack(View view) {
        startActivity(mainIntent);
    }

}
```

EDIT:

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:weightSum="1">

<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:text="@string/button_back"
        android:onClick="onBack"
        android:id="@+id/back"
/>

<TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="EMPTY"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="-500dp"/>


<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.11"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you please post list xml layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your linearlayout height to match_parent, and get rid of the weight as you its used for ratios and doesnt look like you are using it properly. Adding -500 margin is not the right way of doing it. Replace your linearlayout start with the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

If you want your TextView be at the top add it before the button, then add margin to the button to get a margin the text view. If you want your back button on the side next to the textview, add them to a linearlayout with horizontal orientation and which will add them at the top side by side.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use

```
this.setAdapter(adapter);
```

instead.

Comment: The method does not exist in the ListActivity

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the layout `R.layout.shop` has an `ListView` element with id `@android:id/list`. See [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a ListActivity, in your xml, the listview should look like this  with `android:id="@android:id/list"`

```
 <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:background="#00FF00"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>
```

Comment: It has the id of "@android:id/list" (added xml)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that for some reason the LinearLayout was located to low on the screen so I could not see it. I add `android:layout_marginTop="-500dp"` to the ListView and it showed correctly :)

Comment: please look at the answer I suggested, it would help you in a better layout design.